# DBMS: Meaning of the following Relational Calculus Example:

Tags: database, tuples, rdbms, tuple-relational-calculus

The Database has the following tables:

- Hotel:   (hotelNo, hotelName, city)
- Room:    (roomNo, hotelNo, type, price)
- Booking: (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo)
- Guest    (guestNo, guestName, guestAddress)

Describe the following tuple relational calculus in plain English, as well as, convert it to a relational algebra expression.

`{H.hotelName, G.guestName, B1.dateFrom, B2.dateFrom | Hotel(H) ∧Guest(G) ∧ Booking(B1) ∧ Booking(B2) ∧H, hotelNo =B1.hotelNo ∧ G.guestNo = B1.guestNo  ∧ B2.hotelNo = B1.hotelNo ∧ B2.guestNo = B1.guestNo  ∧B2.dateFrom ≠ B1.dateFrom}`

Comment: Accept answer or explain why not please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All pairs of bookings made by the same person at the same hotel that do not start on the same date.